# How we define intervals and function in this example?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

$\left[ 0,1\right] \sim \left( 0,1\right) $

Now

$\left[ 0,1\right] =\left\{ 0,1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...,\frac{1}{n}%
,...\right\} \cup A$

where $A=\left[ 0,1\right] -\left\{ 0,1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...,\frac{1}{%
n},...\right\} $ and

$\left( 0,1\right) =\left\{ \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...,\frac{1}{n}%
,...\right\} \cup A$

where $A=\left( 0,1\right) -\left\{ 0,1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...,\frac{1}{%
n},...\right\} $

then we define a mapping $f:\left[ 0,1\right] \rightarrow \left( 0,1\right) $
by

$f\left( x\right) =\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
x & \text{if} & x\in A \\
\frac{1}{2} & \text{if} & x=0 \\
\frac{1}{n+2} & \text{if} & x=\frac{1}{n}%
\end{array}%
\right. $

Comment: What  is your question?

Comment: What does $\approx$ mean in your context??  Are you trying to prove $(0,1)$ and $[0,1]$ have have the same cardinality?  Then you need to prove $f$ is a bijection. (it is).  I can not comprehend the meaning of your title question "How we define intervals and function in this example".  What is your question.

Comment: yes you are right. I am stuck to understand this function.

Comment: So the function says $f(0) = \frac 12$.  $f(1) =\frac 13$.  $f(\frac 12)=\frac 14$,  $f(\frac 13)= \frac 15$, $f(\frac 14)=\frac 16$ and so on....And for any $x \ne \frac 1n$ (for some $n$) we simply have $f(x) = x$.  The defining of $A$ we a little obtuse  and, IMO, pointless. But $A$ simply means $\{$ all the values in $(0,1)$ that are not in the form $\frac 1n$.

Comment: thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Okay.   All that is says is

Let $A = \{x\in (0,1)| x$ is not in the form $\frac 1n$ for some natural $N$.

Then $[0,1] = \{0\} \cup \{1,\frac 12, \frac 13, \frac 14, ......\} \cup A$.

The function $f$ is "let's shove $0,1$ into $(0,1)$ by shoving $0\mapsto \frac 12$ and $1\mapsto \frac 13$.  But now we have to shove $\frac 12$ and $\frac 13$ somewhere.  We shove them to $\frac 12\mapsto \frac 14$ and $\frac 13\mapsto \frac 15$.  But now we have to shove $\frac 14$ and $\frac 15$ somewhere.  Okay, look, we are just going to shove *every* $\frac 1n \mapsto \frac 1{n+2}$.  That takes care of shove $0,1,$ and everything of the form $\frac 1n$ somewhere.  Everything else will map to themselves:

Thus $f:[0,1] \to (0,1)$ by  $f(x) = x$ if $x \ne 0$ and $x \ne \frac 1n$ for any natural $n$ (note, that *includes* $1 = \frac 11$).  But $f(0) = \frac 12$ and for any $x = \frac 1n$ we do $f(x) = f(\frac 1n) = \frac 1{n+2}$.

Now we can show that $f$ is a bijection:

$f$ is onto:  If $x \in (0,1) $ and $x \ne \frac 1n$ for any $n$ then $x =f(x)$.  And if $x =\frac 1n$, if $x = \frac 12$ then $x = \frac 12 = f(0)$.  And if $x = \frac 1n; n > 2$ then $x =\frac 1n = f(\frac 1{n-2})$.  And so if $x \in (0,1)$ there is a $y \in (0,1)$ so that $x=f(y)$.  So $f$ is onto.

$f$ is one to one:  Suppose $f(x) = f(y)= W$.  If $W \ne \frac 1n$ for any $n$ then $W\ne \frac 1{n+2}$ for any natural $n$ and $W\ne f(\frac 1n)$ for any $n$.  SO $x,y\ne \frac 1n$ for any possible $n$.  So $f(x) =x$ and $f(y) =y$ and $x=y=W$.

.... to be continued....

Comment: thank you very much.....

Answer (score 0):

To show [0,1] is equinumerous to (0,1],
map 0 to 1/2, 1/2 to 1/3, 1/3 to 1/4, ...
and any other number in [0,1] to itself.

In a similar fashion show (0,1] is equinumerous to (0,1).
Thus [0,1] and (0,1) are equinumerous.

Comment: thank you very much